# Multiplying width by a scaling factor in \includegraphics

Tags: graphics

When I include images within my documents I use:

`\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image.png}`.

Sometimes I need the width to be scaled, so I'd use:

`\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{image.png}`.

Sometimes I use the same document to create two different outputs and have an `\ifthen` defined switch that changes certain parts of the document. This includes a `\scalefactor`. When I use then:

```
\newcommand{\scalefactor}{0.5}
\includegraphics[width=\scalefactor*0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
```

I get errors  `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).`

What needs to be done to get this working?

Here is an MWE to help: this works, but when uncommenting the commented line, this is where we get errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\scalefactor}{0.5}
\includegraphics[width=\scalefactor\linewidth]{example-image}

\renewcommand{\scalefactor}{0.35}
\includegraphics[width=\scalefactor\linewidth]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{example-image}

%\includegraphics[width=\scalefactor*0.75\linewidth]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth,scale=\scalefactor]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It seems `scale` is not working when `width` is set?

Comment: er possibly not, You can't expect me to remember my own code:-) you could do `\scalebox{\scalefactor}{\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{...}}` though

Comment: Yep, that's indeed simple and convenient enough.

Comment: or `width={\dimexpr \scalefactor*0.5\linewidth}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way with `expl3` to do the calculation:
so you can use `\imgscale{<original fraction>}` to do the job.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \imgscale } { m }
  {
    \fp_eval:n { \scalefactor * #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\scalefactor}{0.5}
\includegraphics[width=\scalefactor\linewidth]{example-image}

\renewcommand{\scalefactor}{0.35}
\includegraphics[width=\scalefactor\linewidth]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=\imgscale{0.75}\linewidth]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

Of course you can do some more adjustments to make it simpler, for example adding an optional argument for the scale factor.

Comment: Many thanks, I like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\dimexpr` to scale further what's already scaled:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\scalefactor}{0.5}
\includegraphics[width=\scalefactor\linewidth]{example-image}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\scalefactor}{0.35}
\includegraphics[width=\scalefactor\linewidth]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{example-image}

\bigskip

\includegraphics[width=\scalefactor\dimexpr0.75\linewidth]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=0.2625\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

[image]